# UITableView : set the header frame of view in UITableView doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I need to add a **UIButton** in the first section header of **UITableView**.

Here is my code :

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
      if (section == 0) {

        UIButton *createGroupBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, tableView.frame.size.width - 100, 50)];
   // other code...
       return createGroupBtn;
     }
    return nil;
}
```

You see, I have added constraints to the header's frame. (e.g the width is less 100 than tableview's frame's.)

The following is the result in my iPhone:

[image]

Obviously, the red button's width still equals the tableview's.

Do I miss some other important code to make the frame constraint work ?

Comment: Return a view with clear background which contains the button you styled.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're not adding any constraints, you're just setting frames. A section header is always the same width as the table. If you want the button to be narrower, then you should create a UIView, add the button to it (with whatever size you want), and then return the view as the section header.